# Using custom component with react-layout-grid

Tags: reactjs, react-grid-layout

I am using https://github.com/strml/react-grid-layout to create a layout of items which I can resize and move. The problem I'm having has been raised in multiple issues (below) against the repo with little assistance.

1. https://github.com/STRML/react-grid-layout/issues/806
2. https://github.com/STRML/react-grid-layout/issues/299

Here is the bit of code that works fine.

```
<ResponsiveGridLayout
    layouts={this.state.layouts}
    autoSize={autosize}
    breakpoints={breakpoints}
    onLayoutChange={(layout, newLayout) =>
        this.onLayoutChange(layout, newLayout)}>
    <div key="1">...</div>
    <div key="2">...</div>
    <div key="3">...</div>
</ResponsiveGridLayout>
```

I would like the ability to nest a custom component within `<ResponsiveGridLayout>` like so. Where `<CustomComponent />` contains other boxes that can interact.

```
<ResponsiveGridLayout
    layouts={this.state.layouts}
    autoSize={autosize}
    breakpoints={breakpoints}
    onLayoutChange={(layout, newLayout) =>
        this.onLayoutChange(layout, newLayout)}>
    <div key="1">...</div>
    <CustomComponent />
</ResponsiveGridLayout>
```

Here is a basic reproduction of the problem I'm having.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-rncnqr

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You should add key props to CustomComponent

```
<ResponsiveGridLayout
    layouts={this.state.layouts}
    autoSize={autosize}
    breakpoints={breakpoints}
    onLayoutChange={(layout, newLayout) =>
        this.onLayoutChange(layout, newLayout)}>
    <div key="1">...</div>
    <CustomComponent key="2" />
</ResponsiveGridLayout>
```